# Python coding errors are not caught in linter or nor during execution rather they are thrown only when it is mapped or class methods invoked

Tags: python-3.x, interpreter, pylint

I am relatively new to Python. Using Python 3.7 in this example below. The Linter is not catching any of the coding errors nor, it throws any exception when wrong return types are returned. What is the best and formal way of handing such issues?

```
from typing import Tuple
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class MyAbc(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_hello(self) -> Tuple[bool, str, str]:
        # Need the return to be a Tuple of 3 values: bool, str, str
        pass


class ImplementedClass(MyAbc):
    def get_hello(self):
        return True, "Hello"
        # But in the implementation I am returning only 2 values: bool, str
        # This coding error is not caught here


ic: MyAbc = ImplementedClass()
print(ic.get_hello()) # Error escaped

resp1, resp2, resp3 = ic.get_hello()
# The issue is caught only here
# Pylint: Possible unbalanced tuple unpacking with sequence defined at line 15: left side has 3 label(s), right side has 2 value(s)

print(resp1, resp2, resp3)
print(ImplementedClass().get_hello())


def three_returns() -> Tuple[str, str, str]:
    return "one", "two"


print(three_returns()) # Error escaped


def something(data: str) -> str:
    print(type(data), data)
    return 1 # Supposed to return str, returning int, not caught


value: str = something(2) # Expected str but int returned
print(value.upper()) # Pylint: Instance of 'int' has no 'upper' member
```

As mentioned in the code block, when incorrect object is returned, pylint or python will never throw any error. It is only when it is explicitly mapped or any class methods are invoked like str.upper() that's when the error is thrown. This would lead to testing all the paths thoroughly else, it can be sure that code block would work.

Is it how it is and we have live with it or there any better ways to handle it like what we get compile time errors in C++, Java?

Comment: For the benefit of others sharing the details:
https://github.com/leinardi/mypy-pycharm - Configuring Mypy with Pycharm
Pylance / pyright is for VS Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be searching for is a type checker like `mypy`, `pyright` or `pyre`.

Comment: Thanks. I explored it a bit. Your suggestion was helpful. I could configure pyright in Microsoft Code but,  how do I configure it in Pycharm?

Comment: One type checker is enough imo :)